# Can I make a small part of my video frame black and white?

Tags: kdenlive

I am editing some video in Kdenlive and I want to make a subsection of my video black & white.

I know that I can make the whole clip black and white by adding a "saturation" effects. But could I (for example) choose a square within the clip and make only that part black and white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but with different tools and another workflow.

[ Your video] + [ Cropped black & white video part ]  ---TRANSCODING-----> New_video ready for Kdenlive.

To do that, you need to transcode with a tool such as FFmpeg and look for "overlay" and "ffmpeg" keywords.